Как перевести сетевой адаптер в режим мониторинга?
Хочу включить режим мониторинга для работы с Wireshark. У меня macOS, но Wireshark использую через эмулятор UTM в Ubuntu(делаю систему для изучения пентеста), но не уверен что правильно делаю

Для начала ввел команду в терминал macOS:
sudo ifconfig en0 monitor

Получил ошибку:

ifconfig: monitor: bad value

Понял что не для всех сетевых интерфейсов доступен режим мониторинга.
1 Вопрос - Мне нужно купить сетевой адаптер, который поддерживает режим мониторинга и только macOS? Или Linux тоже? Если адаптер будет поддерживать только macOS и я включу в macOS режим мониторинга, а потом зайду в Ubuntu, там режим мониторинга будет работать? Или нужна поддержка Linux?

2 Вопрос - Ту ли я команду вводил? Может я что-то не то ввел. Если что-то не так, пожалуйста, напишите правильные команды.
Если адаптер должен поддерживать и macOS и Linux, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, такие адаптеры.

Макос прям плохой выбор для таких дел, она очень слабо-кастомизуема. И если отвечать на ваш вопрос - под макос надо собирать драйвер (Искать в интернетах драйвер под вашу сетвую и собирать, компилировать на компе). Для внешних устройств то же самое - нет такого который макос "из коробки" переведет в режим мониторинга

сетевушка в линукс виртуальная от виртуалки и поэтому не перевелась в режим.
купи дешевую usb сетевую карту и пробрось usb порт в виртуальную машину. на линуксе понадобится firmware-realtek доустановить если сетевушка на чипе реалтек.
но забегая вперед - вы не увидите весь трафик сети если используется современное оборудование, а только бродкасты, некоторые мультикасты, арп.
для изучения всего трафика нужно на управляемом комутаторе включить зеркалирование порта
